# NiFi - add MDC data to default logger

Tags: apache-nifi, mdc

I'm using NiFi with a mix of built-in processors and custom processors.  I need to be able to append some meta data onto a log message about the processor from which that log message was generated (including from vanilla/default/built-in processors).

The easiest way I can think to do this is to configure MDC for the logger.  The problem is, I don't see where you can configure NiFi to use a custom logger in place of its default one.

I do see that NiFi has the `ComponentLog` interface which can be implemented, and from that I would have enough contextual information to append meta data to my log message.  However, from what I can tell, this is only possible within a custom processor (implement the ComponentLog interface instead of using some 3rd party logger).

Is there some way to do this?  Specifically, I need to log (on every log message) things like which processor and any of the variables / attributes available to that processor.

I can do this by modifying the source and re-building it but I'd really prefer not to have to change/rebuild a fork of NiFi just to do this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up solving this by modifying the logback.xml pattern.  There are built in handlers for non-default things and to interface with MDC.

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html has a good list, specifically `X` which'll let you get to things from MDC.